# How to access data attributes on multiple div element using jquery

Tags: jquery, each, custom-data-attribute

I am new jquery. How to hide the element based on data attributes in div tag.

For my example codes.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("div").each(function()
{
   var c=$( "div" ).data( "role" );
   if(c=="page")
   {
   $(this).hide();
   }
   }
   );
});
</script>


<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'>
<p>sjhfdsjfhdfjdhsf</p>
<p>jfhdzsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfssjfdhss</p>

</div>
<div data-role="pages" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'>
<p>sjhfdsjfhdfjdhsf</p>
<p>jfhdsjfdhss</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.attr` method to access data stored in data attributes via jQuery. Example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').each(function() {
    var c = $(this).attr('data-role');
    if(c === "page") {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'>
  <p>sjhfdsjfhdfjdhsf</p>
  <p>jfhdzsdfsdfdsfdsfdsfssjfdhss</p>
</div>

<div data-role="pages" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'>
  <p>sjhfdsjfhdfjdhsf</p>
  <p>jfhdsjfdhss</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even better than `.attr('data-role')` : `.data('role')`.

Answer (score 0):

To show you another way to do it than a loop, you can select all `<div>` tags you want with CSS selector only, and then hide them.

Some examples:

```
$('[data-role']).hide(); // hides all DOM tags which have a "data-role" attribute.
$('div[data-role]').hide(); // hides all <div> tags which have a "data-role" attribute.
$('div[data-role=page]').hide(); // hides all <div> tags which have a "data-role" attribute equals to "page".
```